Maximize the Area Formed by Roots of a Cubic

Consider the monic cubic equation $f(x) = x^3 + bx^2 + cx+d$, where $b,c,d \in [-1,1]$. Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ be the roots on the complex plane of $f(x)$. What are the values of the coefficients $b,c,d$ that maximize the area of $\triangle \alpha\beta\gamma$?

Numerical simulations suggest that $(b,c,d) = (-1, 1, 1)$ creates the triangle with the maximum area. The polynomial $x^3 - x^2 + x + 1$ has roots
$$\alpha = \frac{1}{3} (1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{33} - 17}} + \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt33 - 17}) \approx -0.54369$$
$$\beta = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt33 - 17}} - \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{33} - 17} + i(-\frac{1}{\sqrt3 \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt33 - 17}} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt 33 - 17}}{2 \sqrt3}) \approx 0.77184 - 1.11514 i$$
$$\gamma= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3 \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt33 - 17}} - \frac{1}{6}\sqrt[3]{3\sqrt{33} - 17} + i(\frac{1}{\sqrt3 \sqrt[3]{3\sqrt33 - 17}} + \frac{\sqrt[3]{3 \sqrt 33 - 17}}{2 \sqrt3}) \approx 0.77184 + 1.11514 i $$
Creating an isosceles triangle with an area of approximately $1.467$ units. The coordinates of the centroid of this triangle are $(\frac{1}{3}, 0)$, and the measure of each base angle is approximately $0.8677$ rad.
I am looking for proof that $(-1,1,1)$ are indeed the coefficients that maximize this triangle, or a derivation of the optimal coefficients. Below are some links that mention the triangle formed by the roots of cubic equations.
Geometry of Cubic Polynomials
On the cubic equation with its Siebeck–Marden–Northshield triangle...
Area of Triangle from Coefficients of its Cubic
Thanks.

@ClaudeLeibovici $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the vertices themselves, as points in the complex plane.

This is a non-linear optimization problem with 3 variables and 6 constraints, of course it can be carried out by computer within milliseconds but it is a terrible job for human, imagine using Lagrange multipliers .... unless we have some tricks.

The solution could be non-unique, as there could be a complementary, equivalent solution with the real root to the right of the two complex roots.

Too long for a comment
By this theorem, let's factor $f(x)=(x-a)(x-(u+iv))(x-(u-iv))$. This give us system: $$\begin{cases}a+(u+iv)+(u-iv)=a+2u=-b \\ a(u+iv)+a(u-iv)+(u+iv)(u-iv)=u^2+v^2+2au=c \\ a(u+iv)(u-iv)=a(u^2+v^2)=-d\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
It is clear that the area $A=|v(a-u)|$, we want to maximize $A$, or equivalently $A^2=v^2(a-u)^2$
Our objective is:
$$\begin{cases}\textrm{Maximize}\ \ \ &A^2=v^2(a-u)^2 \\ \textrm{Subject to}\  &-1\leq \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a+2u&\leq 1 \\ &-1\leq \ \ \ u^2+v^2+2au&\leq 1 \\ &-1\leq \ \ \ \ \ \ a(u^2+v^2)&\leq 1\end{cases} \tag{2}$$
Mathematica gave us numerical solution immediately (that is OP's solution)
NMaximize[{v^2(a-u)^2, a+2u>=-1 && a+2u<=1 && u^2+v^2+2a*u>=-1 && u^2+v^2+2a*u<=1 && a(u^2+v^2)>=-1 && a(u^2+v^2)<=1}, {a,u,v}]

To solve $(2)$, one can find points of vanishing gradient of $A^2$ within the constraints and then use Lagrange multipliers to find suspectable points on boundary of constraints, for which we may find out that the very-boundary point $(a+2u,u^2+v^2+2au,a(u^2+v^2))=(1,1,-1)$ maximizes $A$. However, the verification part is quite long and technical. I doubt that there's better way.

Using your syntax, the maximum is $1.95752$. Using Maximize gives $2.15211$. Which one is correct ? Cheers :-)

@ClaudeLeibovici The latter is correct. I've checked it again, it works well for me regardless of that "N".

There should be an answer here based on noting the gradient is nonvanishing except for at zero-area triangles and using that $(a,u,v)$ is a reparametrization of $(b,c,d)$ which is smooth except at a few bad points, where the area is zero.
